# S3 VPC endpoint , ALB, Route53 and React SPA in a S3 bucket

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint

So I have a S3 bucket used as static website hosting which contains a React SPA. The bucket name has the name like test.net and index.html has been set up as index and error document.

I also have an alias record in R53 which has the mapping of test.net -> alb which has target group of a S3 VPC endpoint. The intension was to have the website only accessible internally.

So right now whenever I access test.net I can see the index.html from the bucket is being accessed, but when I access /login route, I get 404 from S3 which is expected as I don't have the object inside the bucket. Is it possible to configure ALB listener rules in a way that for 403/404 we redirect to index.html for route parsing?

The above pattern is from https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/hosting-internal-https-static-websites-with-alb-s3-and-privatelink/

Previously, I have the similar infra but with CloudFront which has the Error page setting of redirect to /index.html when the response from S3 origin is 403/404. But not sure if it's possible to achieve the same thing but with ALB/S3 VPC endpoint.

Thanks,

Comment: That's rather weird to put a Target Group in front of an S3 VPC endpoint. If you are happy for objects to be publicly accessible, then simply make the bucket (or part of the bucket) public. For private content, use [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which provide time-limited access to private objects in Amazon S3. It also means you don't need to pay for the S3 traffic to go via the Load Balancer.

Comment: The bucket has to be private and I'm following the article https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/hosting-internal-https-static-websites-with-alb-s3-and-privatelink/

Comment: That article seems focused on providing a static website to users via a Direct Connect or VPN connection, not to the public Internet. Does that match your use-case, or are you serving traffic to people on the Internet?

Comment: For me it's the VPN version. The web app is for internal use but previously was publicly available, the CloudFront version.

Comment: The way you typically host an SPA on S3 is to have CloudFront in front of the bucket, and have CloudFront redirect all 404 errors to the `index.html` page. The load balancer only supports changing paths based on the request, not the response, so the load balancer can't help here. Unfortunately, I'm not sure if there is a way to make a CloudFront distribution only available from your VPC. You could put an Nginx server in front of the S3 bucket and manage the redirect in there, but at that point you might as well just host the website itself on the EC2 server.

Comment: It does seem ALB option will not work. I also tried to set TG to point to a lambda that will get the index.html from S3 when the request contains S3 keys that do not exist. But unfortunately my js file is over 1MB, otherwise it's working fine.